# JQuery responsive drop down menu issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, drop-down-menu, woocommerce

I have a responsive drop down jquery menu. For some reason I removed a duplicated jquery library, because it was conflicting with WooCommerce and after that the drop-down responsive menu is not working.

Here is a link to my web site: https://www.santa-film.eu/

As you can see If you click on toggle icon, menu is not showing.
here is the jQuery script used:

```js
jQuery.fn.noSelect = function() {
    var o = "none";
    return this.bind("selectstart dragstart mousedown", function() {
        return !1
    }).css({
        MozUserSelect: o,
        msUserSelect: o,
        webkitUserSelect: o,
        userSelect: o
    })
};
var ias = $.ias({
    container: ".items",
    item: ".item",
    pagination: ".navigation",
    next: ".nav-previous a"
});
ias.extension(new IASSpinnerExtension), $(document).ready(function() {
    $(".dod").click(function() {
        var o = $(this).attr("id");
        1 == o ? ($(".menus").hide(), $(this).attr("id", "0")) : ($(".menus").show(), $(this).attr("id", "1"))
    }), $(".menus").mouseup(function() {
        return !1
    }), $(".dod").mouseup(function() {
        return !1
    }), $(document).mouseup(function() {
        $(".menus").hide(), $(".dod").attr("id", "")
    })
}), $(document).ready(function() {
    $(".rclic").click(function() {
        var o = $(this).attr("id");
        1 == o ? ($(".rmenus").hide(), $(this).attr("id", "0")) : ($(".rmenus").show(), $(this).attr("id", "1"))
    }), $(".rmenus").mouseup(function() {
        return !1
    }), $(".rclic").mouseup(function() {
        return !1
    }), $(document).mouseup(function() {
        $(".rmenus").hide(), $(".rclic").attr("id", "")
    })
}), $(document).ready(function() {
    $(".report").click(function() {
        var o = $(this).attr("id");
        1 == o ? ($(".reportform").hide(), $(this).attr("id", "0")) : ($(".reportform").show(), $(this).attr("id", "1"))
    }), $(".reportform").mouseup(function() {
        return !1
    }), $(".report").mouseup(function() {
        return !1
    }), $(document).mouseup(function() {
        $(".reportform").hide(), $(".report").attr("id", "")
    })
}), $(document).ready(function() {
    $(".buscaboton").click(function() {
        var o = $(this).attr("id");
        1 == o ? ($(".buscaformulario").hide(), $(this).attr("id", "0")) : ($(".buscaformulario").show(), $(this).attr("id", "1"))
    }), $(".buscaformulario").mouseup(function() {
        return !1
    }), $(".buscaboton").mouseup(function() {
        return !1
    }), $(document).mouseup(function() {
        $(".buscaformulario").hide(), $(".buscaboton").attr("id", "")
    })
}), $(document).ready(function() {
    $(".rclic2").click(function() {
        var o = $(this).attr("id");
        1 == o ? ($(".rbuscar").hide(), $(this).attr("id", "0")) : ($(".rbuscar").show(), $(this).attr("id", "1"))
    }), $(".rbuscar").mouseup(function() {
        return !1
    }), $(".rclic2").mouseup(function() {
        return !1
    }), $(document).mouseup(function() {
        $(".rbuscar").hide(), $(".rclic2").attr("id", "")
    })
});
```

So is there a way to get that drop down work correctly?

Thanks

Comment: You can use CSS to create hover menus that open on hover. But you cannot create menus that rely on `onclick()` to function without javascript. Why remove jquery? And as LoicTheAztec said, you need to provide more information.

Answer (score 0):

I search a lot in Internet and I found a solution for conflicting Jquery in wordpress and theme.

So I removed Jquery tag from my header and I used This code to avoid any conflict between my javascript and jquery:

```
jQuery.noConflict();

(function( $ ) {

   // Paste your Code Here...

})( jQuery );
```

like This:

```js
jQuery.noConflict();
(function( $ ) {
$(document).ready(function() {
$(".rclic").click(function() {
    var o = $(this).attr("id");
    1 == o ? ($(".rmenus").hide(), $(this).attr("id", "0")) : ($(".rmenus").show(), $(this).attr("id", "1"))
}), $(".rmenus").mouseup(function() {
    return !1
}), $(".rclic").mouseup(function() {
    return !1
}), $(document).mouseup(function() {
    $(".rmenus").hide(), $(".rclic").attr("id", "")
})
}), $(document).ready(function() {
$(".report").click(function() {
    var o = $(this).attr("id");
    1 == o ? ($(".reportform").hide(), $(this).attr("id", "0")) : ($(".reportform").show(), $(this).attr("id", "1"))
}), $(".reportform").mouseup(function() {
    return !1
}), $(".report").mouseup(function() {
    return !1
}), $(document).mouseup(function() {
    $(".reportform").hide(), $(".report").attr("id", "")
})
}), $(document).ready(function() {
$(".buscaboton").click(function() {
    var o = $(this).attr("id");
    1 == o ? ($(".buscaformulario").hide(), $(this).attr("id", "0")) : ($(".buscaformulario").show(), $(this).attr("id", "1"))
}), $(".buscaformulario").mouseup(function() {
    return !1
}), $(".buscaboton").mouseup(function() {
    return !1
}), $(document).mouseup(function() {
    $(".buscaformulario").hide(), $(".buscaboton").attr("id", "")
})
}), $(document).ready(function() {
$(".rclic2").click(function() {
    var o = $(this).attr("id");
    1 == o ? ($(".rbuscar").hide(), $(this).attr("id", "0")) : ($(".rbuscar").show(), $(this).attr("id", "1"))
}), $(".rbuscar").mouseup(function() {
    return !1
}), $(".rclic2").mouseup(function() {
    return !1
}), $(document).mouseup(function() {
    $(".rbuscar").hide(), $(".rclic2").attr("id", "")
})
});
})( jQuery );
```

I share this solution to help other people may have this problem.